# Android Button background is not recognizing/using the drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, button

I want to add a background to a button, as I have already done several times. I have a drawable resource file with the appropriate background. However, if I link this, it will not be accepted, instead only one color will be used as the background.
I had the suspicion that it could be a mistake in my Styles.xml but nothing is called too colored in these. What can be the reasons why Android Studio does not recognize a background or where could I have defined a general theme of how buttons should look? I can't remember having put on something like that. I tried something similar with an EditText, I had no problems here, so I think it is a specific button problem.
Also if I change the background color to a plain whit it is not changing anything and still showing a dark blue.

Update: If I change the preview style (upper middel of the preview) to DialogStyle the button background works. How can that be if there is nothing defined in der styles?

Update: I added a new version of my button this time initializing the background in a extra style. Result is that it is still not showing the right color. I also tried it with black but nothing happend.

Thanks for any help.

**Button**

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRegistrieren"
                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btnbackground"
                android:onClick="WriteData"
                android:text="@string/Registrieren"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="16dp"></Button>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style
        name="SplashTheme"
        parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>



    <style
        name="SecondTheme"
        parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**btnbackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:centerColor="#FF5256AC"
        android:endColor="#FF662D91"
        android:startColor="#FF29ABE2"
        android:type="linear" />


    <corners android:radius="150dp">

    </corners>

</shape>
```

**Button with Theme**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Anmelden"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonStyle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="426dp"
        />
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="edmt.dev.androideatitv2client">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme">
        <activity android:name=".PasswordActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UpdatePasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UpdateProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <service android:name=".services.MyFCMServices">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Its better if you post your layout because that can have an effect ,otherwise I tested your button and background and they work .Styles have nothing to do with it since you didn't include the attribute in your button..Have you tried double clicking on preview tab or synchronize on the top left ?.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I tried syncronizing. What I did a minute ago is that I changed preview mode to DialogStyle (have a look at my styles) and that made it working. How can that be if their is nothing declared in the styles.xml?

Comment: try it inside a regular linear layout ,it works I swear :).

Comment: I tried it did not work hahah it only works if i change to dialogstyle

Comment: I just tried this all myself and it works fine for me... I don't think the styles have anything to do with it because you're not referencing the styles with the button. However, you can definitely try referencing the background in a style, and then giving the button that style and see if anything different happens

Comment: @EthanShoe like I said I also have no idea why the styles are involved but somehow they are.  tried to use a style the way you told me: However if i use `theme=newtheme` as a general theme at the top of my layout it works but it is putting the background to all textview etc. what is not making it easier. If I put it as a theme for the button it is not changing anything. + I also added my manifst

Comment: Could you show us your backend please ?

Comment: @ZaKAmiar Thanks for your answer! What exactly do you mean by backend? You mean the Java activities or what? If so I tried it out in nearly all activities and it never worked. The small round preview next to the android: background command shows the correct drawable but as soon as the program is running it is not accepted (also in the preview).

Comment: Yes, i mean Java Activities,  i think you have to define Width and height of your shape

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add `Width` and `Height` to your `Shape`in

**btnbackground.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="#FF5256AC"
    android:endColor="#FF662D91"
    android:startColor="#FF29ABE2"
    android:type="linear" />


<corners android:radius="150dp">

</corners>
```

If you don't use AndroidX, you have to change your Theme from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style
    name="SplashTheme"
    parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
</style>



<style
    name="SecondTheme"
    parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

**Button**

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Anmelden"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

here's the result : 
[image]

Comment: That worked! The problem was in the Styles.xml. Exactly what You wrote. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem changing the theme from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Hope it helps and happy coding!

Comment: You could explain why/how this solution worked.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review due to you being a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & helpful.  This comment is intended to help you make a good answer into an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the view from `Button` to `ImageButton`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i tried that and it its working. However this is a technically unattractive solution because even when inserting a framelayout in lollipop there will be problems with the labeling of the button.